# In TWIG when accessing related objects I get Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I try to display the information from the tables I get the following error:

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.MissionID AS MissionID_1, t0.Date AS Date_2, t0.Flighttime AS Flighttime_3, t0.PatientID AS PatientID_4, t0.Companion1 AS Companion1_5, t0.Companion2 AS Companion2_6, t0.Companion3 AS Companion3_7, t0.Companion4 AS Companion4_8, t0.Comments AS Comments_9, t0.AddChangeID AS AddChangeID_10, t0.AddChangeDate AS AddChangeDate_11, t0.Miles AS Miles_12 FROM leg t0 WHERE t0.MissionID = ?' with params [101]:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.Date' in 'field list'") in leg/list.html.twig at line 24.

The issue only occurs when I try to access anything from the Mission table. If I remove the line where I am trying to get the data from the mission table everything works fine. I use the same method for accessing data from other tables and I don't have any issues.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening.

In my twig template I have the following:

```
<tbody>
    {% for leg in legs %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ leg.missionid.MissionID }}</td>
            <td>{{ leg.legnumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ leg.missionid.Date }}</td>
            <td>{{ leg.originid.Identifier }}</td>
            <td>{{ leg.destinationid.Identifier }}</td>
            <td>{{ leg.legnumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ leg.pilotid.PilotID }}</td>
        </tr>...
```

My Entities are:

```
/**
 * Mission
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="leg")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Mission
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="MissionID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $missionid;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;

/**
 * Leg
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="leg", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="FK_MissionID", columns={"MissionID"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_StatusID", columns={"StatusID"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_PilotID", columns={"PilotID"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_TypeID", columns={"TypeID"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_OriginID", columns={"OriginID"}), @ORM\Index(name="FK_DestinationID", columns={"DestinationID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Leg
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="LegID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $legid;
...
   /**
     * @var \Location
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="DestinationID", referencedColumnName="LocationID")
     * })
     */
    private $destinationid;

    /**
     * @var \Mission
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Mission")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="MissionID", referencedColumnName="MissionID")
     * })
     */
    private $missionid;

    /**
     * @var \Location
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="OriginID", referencedColumnName="LocationID")
     * })
     */
    private $originid;

    /**
     * @var \Pilot
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Pilot")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="PilotID", referencedColumnName="PilotID")
     * })
     */
    private $pilotid;
```

Comment: Try {{ dump(leg) }} in twig, and 'php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force' in command line.

Comment: Thanks that helps a lot. It looks like the mission record was not loaded, none of the data in the object is valid. I will have to dig into that any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Found my issue. Dumb mistake! /**
 * Mission
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="leg")  <<<<<<< should be mission
 * @ORM\Entity
 */